# Formula field gets populated with respect to other fields

Tags: formula, validation

Im using PE.[image]

For the calculating of Total commission user must enter the value in either one this two fields(ie., in Consultant Commission % on Opportunity(Percent datatype )or Fixed Value(currency datatype)).If i enter value in Consultant Commission field then (Total commission(Formula field currency) = Consultant Commission % on Opportunity * Final purchase price).If i enter the value in "Fixed value" field the (Total commission =Fixed value) .Im using PE

Note:TC_c=Consultant Commission % on Opportunity * Final purchase price

I tried this formula 
IF( NOT ISBLANK( Fixed_value__c ), Fixed_value__c , TC__c   )

but I getting this error
**Formula(s) that reference this field are no longer valid: Compiled formula is too big to execute (7,807 characters). Maximum size is 5,000 characters (Related field: Formula**

Comment: What is the exact formula you're using for `TC__c`? The formula above isn't large which suggests that `TC__c` is, or it's including another formula field which is built from a large expression. Add all of the relevant formulae to the question and hopefully we'll be able to condense them a little!

Comment: thanks for replay TC_c is a formula field(currency) TC__c=Consultant Commission % on Opportunity * Final purchase price(for e.g TC__c=(1.8%)*(1100000)=19800)
TC__c=19800.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

`IF(Fixed_value__c!=0 , Fixed_value__c , TC__c)`